# Node js встроенный cluster vs pm2 cluster

Tags: node.js, cluster, pm2

Помогите разобраться с кластеризацией pm2 и встроенной в node js. Ниже приведён код файла app.js, который и будет запущен менеджером pm2.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я использую встроенную кластеризацию ноды. После запуска, командой pm2 monit я вижу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4 воркера, memory 37 MB.

Теперь избавляемся от кластеризации ноды, запуская воркер напрямую.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И указываем pm2 использовать кластеризацию.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получаем 4 воркера, каждый по 44 MB memory.

Хочу разобраться почему так, что лучше использовать? Почему 4 кластера ноды жрут меньше mem, чем один кластер pm2? Может я в чем то не разобрался?

Answer (score 0):

Сам спросил, сам ответил. pm2 просто запускает несколько одинаковых процессов, и выступает в роле балансировщика. Так же pm2 предоставляет удобное api для работы со своими "кластерами".